# Why metrics from prometheus are not propagated to custom metrics api via prometheus adapter?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I have prometheus deployed in my cluster within my custom namespace and prometheus adapter deployed within the same cluster and within the same namespace:

[image]

But when I execute:

```
$ kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

I see empty response:

```
{"kind":"APIResourceList","apiVersion":"v1","groupVersion":"custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1","resources":[]}
```

Although prometheus contains metrics:

[image]

I configured prometheus url inside prometheus adapter YML:

[image]

How to fix it ?

Comment: Any error in prometheus adapter pod logs, Kubernetes API Server logs, prometheus logs?

Comment: Adapter container log is empty

Comment: that ip is ip of prometheus server ip? is that accessible from inside adapter pod?

Comment: This is ip of the prometheus load balancer. This balancer is a public available(even from my mobile phone internet)

Comment: Where could I find *Kubernetes API Server logs* ?

Comment: prometheus log is empty too

Comment: If you are on GKE then since its managed service you will not have access to API server and its logs.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu ok, any ideas how to troubleshoot my issue?

Comment: I am surprised that no logs at all in adapter..maybe just redeploy the adapter and check if there is any logs..is the adapter ready state? There are two container in the adapter pod

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu I see following audit log for prometheus adapter: http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2020/02/09/0005/3037/338909/09/db312ff571.jpg of

Comment: I am afraid I use wrong prometheus ip addres and port to prometheus. Could you please exaplain me the place where I can check it ?

Comment: How could I check if prometheus available from adapter pod ?

Comment: For now I use following ip: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2020/02/09/0005/3037/338909/09/b77c525770.jpg

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu adapter status: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2020/02/09/0005/3037/338909/09/306bdf5a0e.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207494/discussion-between-arghya-sadhu-and-gstackoverflow).

Comment: Did you fix that ? I have the same problem.